# How can I validate Mobile/Landline Number formatting using MVC.Net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Pretty simple question - validating International Mobile/Landline Number using Data Annotations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single "international" phone number standard, but you can do some validation.  For example:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^([\+]|0)[(\s]{0,1}[2-9][0-9]{0,2}[\s-)]{0,2}[0-9][0-9][0-9\s-]*[0-9]$")]
```

This allows, for example: `044 123-456`, `+2 12-12456`, `+(234) 56-56-452`.  See here for more kinds of regular expressions for phone numbers:

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=phone+number&c=0&m=0&ps=20&p=12

Answer (score -1):

MVC has built in support for telephone numbers:

```
[DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

See the MSDN reference page for more information on the validatation types available: [DataType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.datatype%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: DataType does not do any validation.  You need a ValidationAttribute to do validation.  DataType is used with EditorTemplates to format the type correctly.