# ASP.Net Validation Expressions for Phone Numbers

Tags: asp.net

I need a Validation Expression to validate an Egyptian mobile number as an input in my form.

Egyptian Mobile Number:

- must Contain 11 Digits
- must Begin with '01'
- the third digit must be either '2' or '1' or '0'

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.NET? There are lots of tutorials for text validation. Is the phone number entered in a `TextBox`? If so you can use the `TextChanged` event to handle your key entries. Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm Using C#
And Yes the phone number is Entered in a Text Box
I'm using "The Regular Expression Validator" which is in the toolbox of the visual Studio 

And i Need to write an expression in the Expression-Field in the properties panel ...

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028735/how-can-i-validate-mobile-landline-number-formatting-using-mvc-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to support starting '+' characters, spaces or '-' signs inside your phone number? If you don't and you need to support just exact what you said then you can use this pattern:

```
"^01[0-2][0-9]{8}$"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , your answer has worked perfectly with me ^_^